# Python3 - ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to do some experimental web-scraping and have a query on whether it is possible to overcome ValueError under the following scenario. As a sample, the following 5 data fields are what I would like to web-scrape:

```
1) Car Model: Honda Fit Auto 1.3
2) Price: S$19,000
3) Date post: 3 weeks ago by back_packer
4) Depreciation: S$8,362.75
5) Registration Date: 15 Jan 2010
```

From the website's html, the data for 2) to 5) are under the same tag

```
<p class="cU-b cU-d">3 weeks ago by <a href="/back_packer" rel="nofollow " 
target="_blank">back_packer</a></p>
<p class="cU-b cU-d">S$19,000</p>
<p class="cU-b cU-d">S$8,362.75</p>
<p class="cU-b cU-d">15 Jan 2010</p>
```

## As such, I tried running the following Python codes.

```
def getHTML(link, counter):
    return bs(get(link.format(counter)).content, "html.parser")

PAGE_URL = 'https://sg.carousell.com/categories/cars-32/cars-for-sale-1173/'
CAR_URL = 'https://sg.carousell.com/p/{}'

car = dict()
content = getHTML(CAR_URL, car_id).find('div', {'class': 'aG-c aG-b'})
car['Model'] = content.find('p', {'class': 'cU-b cU-e'}).text

car['Post'], car['Price'], car['Deprec'], car['Regstr_Date'] = {info.text for 
info in content.find_all('p', {'class': 'cU-b cU-d'})}
```

======================================

When I tried running, I would encounter "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)". I suspect that the error arose from one at least one of the car record having a missing field for either post, price, depreciation or registration date.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post sample html code/url and desired output?

Comment: Hi Andrej, thks for the feedback. I have tried to edit my question. Hopefully it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

The page isn't very scrapping friendly, so you can use trial and error method until you get your results right. My attempt is here (I substituted missing values for `"-"`, at least it won't throw ValueError but you need to check if it scrapes correct info):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from requests import get
import re
from pprint import pprint


def getHTML(link, counter):
    return bs(get(link.format(counter)).content, "html.parser")

PAGE_URL = 'https://sg.carousell.com/categories/cars-32/cars-for-sale-1173/'
CAR_URL = 'https://sg.carousell.com/p/{}'

# car_id = 'mazda-3-sedan-auto-1-5-182030279'
car_id = 'nissan-nv200-1-5-manual-182141686'
# car_id = 'toyota-corolla-axio-1-5-auto-x-177344405'

car = {}
content = getHTML(CAR_URL, car_id).find('div', {'class': 'aG-c aG-b'})
car['Model'] = content.find('p', {'class': 'cU-b cU-e'}).text

data = []
for p in content.select('section.bi-c.bi-h p.cU-b.cU-d')[:4]:
    if re.match(r'\d+\s+Likes', p.text):
        break
    data.append(p.text)

car['Post'], car['Price'], car['Deprec'], car['Regstr_Date'], *_ = data + ['-'] * 4

# swap Deprec and Registration Date?
if car['Deprec'] != '-' and '$' not in car['Deprec']:
    car['Regstr_Date'], car['Deprec'] = car['Deprec'], car['Regstr_Date']

pprint(car)
```

Prints for this car:

```
{'Deprec': '-',
 'Model': 'Nissan NV200 1.5 Manual',
 'Post': 'an hour ago by rubberr',
 'Price': 'S$25,800',
 'Regstr_Date': '-'}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Really appreciate it ^^